# Playing Audio Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have a small jQuery function to play audio when a user clicks the link.  I don't need any controls, they are short samples.  I just want to play anytime a user clicks.  Here is the html for the section that should play;

```
    </div class="classicalRecordings">
      <a href="#" class="play" data-audio-src="music/classical/open.mp3">Open song</a>
    </div>
```

Then this is the jQuery to play the sound;

```
        function playMusic(){
          var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
          var audioElementSrc = $(this).attr('data-audio-src');
          audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioElementSrc);
          $.get();
          audioElement.addEventListener("load", function(){
              audioElement.play();
          }, true);
      } 
      $(function(){
          $('.play').click(playMusic);
      });
```

It doesn't seem to work.  I think it has to do with the src variable, I am not sure I am passing it to the audioElement correctly. I have tested using an alert to be sure I am grabbing the data-audio-src correctly.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the event you're looking for is the loadeddata event.

```
    function playMusic(){
      var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
      var audioElementSrc = $(this).attr('data-audio-src');
      audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioElementSrc);
      $.get();
      // changed "load" t0 "loadeddata"
      audioElement.addEventListener("loadeddata", function(){
          audioElement.play();
      }, true);
  } 
  $(function(){
      $('.play').click(playMusic);
  });
```

Although you could probably be better off having a static audio element and changing the src attribute on user clicks rather than creating a new audio element.

```
// example  
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
audio.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
     this.play();
}, true);
function playMusic() {
    var audioElementSrc = $(this).attr('data-audio-src');
    audio.setAttribute('src', audioElementSrc);
};
$('.play').click(playMusic);
```

There is a framework for this that is worth checking out. [ListenJS](https://github.com/Nindaff/ListenJS). I wrote it :)

Comment: This worked perfect. I then added $('.pause').click(function() {
        audioElement.pause();
        });
to the playMusic function to create a way to stop what is playing.  This will work great for a simple list that need to just play samples

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<audio id="sound">
  <source src="music/classical/open.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

And from code:

```
  $(function(){
      $('#sound').get(0).play();
  });
```